# Why does this json4s code work in the scala repl but fail to compile?

Tags: json, scala, json4s, scala-2.11

I'm converting a json-like string into json, and the following code works in the scala repl

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

val value = "{100:1.50;500:1.00;1000:0.50}"

val data = value.stripPrefix("{").stripSuffix("}").split(";").map(a => {
  val b = a.split(":")
  (b(0),b(1))
}).toMap
compact(render(data))
```

But when it is compiled, I'm getting the following error

```
[error] ... type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
[error]  required: org.json4s.JValue
[error]     (which expands to)  org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
[error]       compact(render(data))
[error]                      ^
```

Why is this, and how might I fix it?

I suspect something with the type system that is over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`render()`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/native/src/main/scala/org/json4s/native/JsonMethods.scala#L32) is imported from `JsonMethods._` and it actually requires a JValue. You have imported an implicit [`map2jvalue`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonDSL.scala#L70) twice from those two imports `import org.json4s.JsonDSL._` and `import org.json4s.JsonDSL.WithDouble._`.

I suspect that the compiler didn't find the implicit due to the ambiguous imports, try to be more selective: [the 3rd import seems redundant](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonDSL.scala#L61) (the one with `JsonDSL.WithDouble._`).

Sometimes you can run scalac with -Xlog-implicits to see why implicits are not used.

Comment: You were right! Thanks. Great answer. I removed the redundant, `import org.json4s.JsonDSL._`, and everything worked correctly. And thanks for the great note about `-Xlog-implicits`!